# Choosing a model based on ACF and PACF vs information Criterion

Tags: r, arima, aic, bic, univariate

I'm currently doing some univariate forecasting using a small data set of about 36 observations and R software for analysis.

I've found that the basic visual inspection of ACFs and PACFs coupled with ADF tests for checking for stationarity yields different lag selection than it does  when using information criterion.

for example when using visual inspection of the data  it would appear that the appropriate lag selection for this model would be an AR(1),

[image]

However upon running the command `auto.arima()` I find that the results are very different from my visual inspection.

> `Series: sample 
>   ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean 
>   Coefficients:
>            ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2      mean
>         1.8850  -0.9482  -1.5561  0.7891  725.9292
>   s.e.  0.0471   0.0443   0.2045  0.2472   19.7146
>   sigma^2 estimated as 1136:  log likelihood=-177.03`

In terms of model selection which method of selection is preferred? Visual inspection of ACF and PACF or the use of a selected Information criterion?

Comment: There have been a large number (hundreds?) of similar questions, you might benefit from looking some of them up.

Comment: @RichardHardy I make sure to dig through the site to see if I can find something that answers this question. I cant seem to find anything. if you know of a related question please link it to me.